# why xcode's suggested error fix (goes back and forth with no end) in these statements?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have this line, written with Swift 1.2 using XCode 6

```
self.mainMenuButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Box.fontName, size: mainMenuButton.titleLabel?.font.pointSize!)
```

it shows this error

> operand of postfix "!" should have an optional type

it basically suggests that I change it to this

```
self.mainMenuButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Box.fontName, size: mainMenuButton.titleLabel?.font.pointSize)
```

and when done it requires that i put the `!` back like in the first line, so it loops in the suggestions without ending...

why does this happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I have encountered this problem multiple times! Really confusing. The problems lies in the UIFont init statement:

```
UIFont(name: ..., size: mainMenuButton.titleLabel?.font.pointSize!)
```

The problem is that the UIFont initializer requires a non-optional `size` argument. But in your code, `mainMenuButton.titleLabel?`, the `?` says that `mainMenuButton.titleLabel?.font.pointSize!` can return an optional, regardless of whether you put a `!` at the end.

### Solution

The solution is to change the `?` behind `titleLabel` to a `!`.

### Explanation for error fix going back and forth

Xcode is not smart enough to know that the `?` is the root cause of the problem, it just thinks that since the expression ultimately returns `pointSize`, you should add a `!` to ensure that `pointSize` is not nil. But, as shown in the documentation, `pointSize` is not an optional! So there's no need to unwrap it using `!`. That's why Xcode suggests to remove the `!`. But removing it causes the expression to be return an optional! And the `size` argument only allows non-optionals! So the Fix-It cycles back and forth...

### Edit

Also, I tested it and this error going back and forth problem is fixed in Xcode 7. Compared to Xcode 7, Xcode 6 is already obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

As blip explained, watch out for "?"
These typically pop up when you need to use a "!" or "?" and Xcode typically falls back to "?".
If you are trying to display something on the user's screw and it shows as optional("blah blah"), look for any "?" leading up to the code that prints the line and force unwrap it "!"